# Controls Present within DataTemplate of ItemsControl on Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have an ItemsControl that is bound to a collection.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Classroom.Teachers}">
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBox x:Name="tbx" Width="40"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="cmb" Width="100"/>
    <Button Click="OnClick">
      <TextBlock Text="Add"/>
    </Button>
  </StackPanel>
  <DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In the `OnClick` handler of the button how to I get the values of `tbx` and `cmb` that are local to the DataTemplate of the button which was clicked?

Comment: You need `FrameworkTemplate.FindName Method (String, FrameworkElement)` for this purpose like the duplicate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    Panel panel = btn.Parent as Panel;

    TextBox tbx = panel.Children[0] as TextBox;
    string s = tbx.Text;

    ComboBox cmb = panel.Children[1] as ComboBox;
    object item = cmb.SelectedItem;
}
```

But note that a better approach would be to bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` and the `SelectedItem` property of the `ComboBox` to some properties of your `Teacher` class and access these instead.